# Vue reactive array data outputs different values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Im quite new to the vue reactive data workflow, and I'm attempting to make a image uploader, and its mainly working. Im trying to remove all `true` primary values from the images in the array, before updating a specific one. But I need to make a check on the "primary" values in the image array so i can make the conditional change.

I have left the image creation function at the bottom so you can see how this is made. the parent component gets all the data from server via ajax if being used to edit images this is the `_images` prop.

For some reason when i reference the array as `images[key].primary`, I get a different value than if I output the whole array in the console. Any ideas whats happening here?

**Goal**

Currently on the child  component im clicking a make primary button and emitting the update to this component. Then in the update Method attempting to check if request is a new primary image request and make primary false on all other images. Then setting the requested image as primary. So a primary on toggle so there is only ever one primary image.

currently Im testing two images, in turn setting each one as primary true, and watching the other automatically turn false, but by the third click they are both true and nothing happens. Any ideas whats happening here?

**Parent Component (v-image-upload):**

```
export default {

  components: {
    'v-image': image
  },
  props: ['_errors', '_images', '_isMultiple'],
  data() {
    return {
      images: _.cloneDeep(this._images),
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateImage(request) {

      //ISSUE: current images = true,true | images = false,true
      console.log('current images', this.images[0].primary, this.images[1].primary, );
      console.log('images', this.images);

      if (request.form.primary && !this.images[request.key].primary) {

        //reset all primary images
        $.each(this.images, (index, value) => {
              let image = value;
              image.primary = false;

              this.$set(this.images, index, image);
            }
              //update images with new image
              this.$set(this.images, request.key, request.form);
          },
          onFileChange(e) {
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

            if (files.length) {
              $.each(files, (index, file) => {
                this.createImage(file);
              });
            }
            e.target.value = '';
          },
          createImage(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let fileNameSegments = file.name.split('.');
            let fileName = fileNameSegments[0];
            let fileExtension = fileNameSegments[1];
            let validExtnesions = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'];
            let placeholderImage = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + 'img/site/default/placeholder-image.png';
            let primary = (this.images.length == 0) ? true : false;


            reader.onload = (e) => {
              let image = ($.inArray(fileExtension, validExtnesions) == -1) ? placeholderImage : e.target.result;
              let data = {
                name: fileName,
                extension: fileExtension,
                source: image,
                description: null,
                primary: primary,
                image_directory: null,
              };

              this.$set(this.images, this.images.length, data);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

          },
      }
    }
```

**Child Compononet (v-image):**

```
    export default {
    props: ['_imgKey', '_image', '_errors'],
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                id: _.clone(this._image.id),
                name: _.clone(this._image.name),
                description: _.clone(this._image.description),
                primary: _.clone(this._image.primary),
                extension: _.clone(this._image.extension),
                image_directory: _.clone(this._image.image_directory),
                source: _.clone(this._image.source),
            },
        }
    },
    watch: {
        _image: {
            handler(value) {
                console.log('_image watch', this._imgKey, value.primary);
                this.form.id = _.clone(value.id);
                this.form.name = _.clone(value.name);
                this.form.primary = _.clone(value.primary);
                this.form.source = _.clone(value.source);
                this.form.image_directory = _.clone(value.image_directory);

            }, deep: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updatePrimary() {
            this.form.primary = true;
            this.updateImage();
        },
        updateImage() {
            this.$emit('updateImage', {key: this._imgKey, form: this.form});
        },
        removeImage() {
            this.$emit('removeImage', this._imgKey);

        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have been watching the vue developer tools for any changes to the image array. I push the primary button on the false image in the  component this emits to the parent and calls the updateImage method. The first and second reset and update works, and changes the values. The issue has been tracked to: **The 2nd 'after update' (true,false) does not match the third 'before reset'(true,true).**

- I made the previous changes mensioned in the comments and added a clone deep to both components data to prevent odd reactivity behaviour.
- I checked the event log: 3x `UpdateImage $emit by <VImage>` which was expected.

*Note: I moved the previous reset logic into the `resetPrimary()` method.*

```
     updateImage(request) {
           console.log('update', request.key, request.form.primary);
           console.log('b4 reset', this.images[0].primary, this.images[1].primary);
           this.resetPrimary(request);
           console.log('after reset', this.images[0].primary, this.images[1].primary);
           this.$set(this.images, request.key, request.form);
           console.log('after update', this.images[0].primary, this.images[1].primary);
    },
```

output:

```
//First click - Image 1 (Expected)
update 1 true
b4 reset true false
after reset false false
after update false true

//Second click - Image 0 (Expected)
update 0 true
b4 reset false true
after reset false false
after update true false

//Third click - Image 1 (What?)
update 1 true
b4 reset true true //should be true false
after reset true true
after update true true
```

It appears that when attempting to update the same image a second time it somehow ignores the fact it has previously been reset to false.

Comment: What is the current outcome and what is the expected outcome?  And also, you are indirectly modifying the `prop` `_images` which is a no-no.

Comment: @StevenB. ..also if this is a no no, how would I set the data from prop values without affecting the prop directly?

Comment: Don't invoke the value of a `data` parameter with a `prop`. Assign to it from the `created` hook, as a side note.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thats strange the documentation has a initialCounter example that does props like I have. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: `initialCounter` is a primitive value so references won't carry.  _images is an array so images will have reference to the _images array of objects.  You need to emit changes to the parent or you need to make a deep copy and modify that.

Comment: @StevenB. Thanks for explanation. I have used lodash cloneDeep to achieve this, although Im still getting same issue.